# Search a large array in Javascript more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, optimization

I am writing a script that allows organisation of records and data.

However a problem right now is I use an array to store a large amount of information and at a point in my script this array is searched for a matching id and updated. The data search begins to get quite slow when the array size is more than 200 elements.

Is there any way to more efficiently search the array?

I am currently using find.(function(a){return x == y};);

Each element in my array is also a tuple.

Sample code:

```
   onPipelineChanged: function(component, event, helper)
   {
    var titleid = event.getParam("titleid");
    var title = event.getParam("title");
    var maxSeats = event.getParam("maxSeats");
    var seatsInUse = event.getParam("seatsInUse");  
    var item = event.getParam("item"); //This is the item that was moved.
    var allGuestsList = component.get("v.allItems");

    //Searches guest list for matching guest of who got moved.
    var actualGuest = allGuestsList.find(function(moving){return moving.id == item.id;}); //***REALLY INEFFICIENT***
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is your slowdown?  At a few hundred objects, this would be expected to take very little time.

Comment: Use a different data structure. Maybe a `Map`, keyed by the id, or an array sorted by id.